# Python Compute Jacobian numerically

Tags: python, differential-equations

Hi I have a class with the purpose to solve system of Differential equations, this class contains a class named Rhs (right hand side) that contains all the feature of the differential problem: init_time , final_time , Initial value , function(that is a numpy.array containing lambda function)

when I have a system of differential equation the functions are managed in this way :

```
eq1 = lambda t,u : a*(u[0]-u[0]*u[1]);
eq2 = lambda t,u : -c*(u[1]-u[0]*u[1]);

func1 = np.array([eq1,eq2])

y0      = np.array([2.,1.])
system1 = rhs.Rhs(func1, 0,10,y0,500 )
```

using the parameter above the class Rhs is completed ! it have a method to return the value of each function, and a method for compute the derivate of each of function:

```
def f(self,ti,ui):
       return  np.array([function(ti,ui) for function in self.func])     


def Df(self,ti,ui):
      eps = 10e-12
      return (self.f(ti,ui+eps) - self.f(ti,ui-eps) )/(2*eps)
```

Now I have a big problem, in order to create a class to solve an implicit method I have to compute the Jacobian of the function ! but I have not idea how to do this ! 
I wrote down this but doesn't works :

```
   def J(self,ti,ui):   
     self.t = ti 
     self.u = ui
     Jac = np.zeros((len(ui),len(ui)))
     n = len(ui)
     eps = 1e-12
     for i in range(n):
         for j in range(n):
             Jac[i,j] = self.Df(ti,ui) 

     return Jac
```